# react-native-router-flux tabbar position top

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

How to change the position of the tabbar? I hope for many apps, there needs to be a tabbar on **top** rather than having that at bottom...

I'm expecting something like this:

```
<Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
    <Scene key="somekey" tabs={true} 
        tabBarStyle={{position:'top'}}>         <==  How do I do this?

             # My tabs here as scenes

    </Scene>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the tabBar has an absolute positioning. You have to set the *top* attribute.

```
tabBarStyle={{top:0}}
```

*You have to consider the Status Bar's height and NavBar's height, in order to have a correct positioning.*

p.s: I don't know if you are aware of this, but avoid using *inline-styles*. If it was only for the sake of the example, dismiss my advice. :P

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the property:

**tabBarPosition='top'**

```
<Scene tabBarPosition='top' tabs={true} key="myTabBar" >
```

**see the doc** https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#tabs-tabs-or-scene-tabs